# Using Drupal to manage my database

Tags: database, drupal

In my Drupal site, i would like to manage my database. What i am looking for is that i want to get data from user and store them in my database and also want to retrieve the data from database and show it in the site. PLease help, & view me as a beginner.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add fields to the user? You add fields to the user at "admin/config/people/accounts/fields".

Comment: @2pha :Thanks, but i want to collect detailed informations regarding each users i have added in my Users. can you help, pls.

Comment: Add fields to the user at the path stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

Creating a custom content type allows to create forms that can collect data from users and it will handle the save for you, visit '/admin/structure/types' to manage your content types.

You might need to enable some core modules and even install some custom modules if you want advanced field types.

the custom module **views** offers many ways of displaying the data you have in your database.

you might be interested in visiting '/admin/people/permissions' to set some permission on who can see what.

## Solution 2

If for some reason you need to handle the database yourself. then you will need to write a drupal module.

I suggest you find a book of your choosing and focus on

- Module System
- Database layer
- Form API

You can also find examples here [Drupal Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), the module dbtng_example is a good start ;)